# distinct on large table takes too long time in django

Tags: python, django, distinct

I have a large dataset with over 1m records. It has a manytomany field that causes duplicate returns on filtering.

models.py:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)


class Catalogue(models.Model):
    link = models.TextField(null=False)
    image = models.TextField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100, null=True)
    type = models.ManyToManyField(Type, db_index=True)
    datetime = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
last2week_q = Q(datetime__gte=last2week)
type_q = Q(type__in=intersections)
city_district_q = (Q(*[Q(city__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR) |
                   Q(*[Q(district__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR))

models.Catalogue.objects.filter(last2week_q & type_q & city_district_q).order_by('-datetime').distinct()
```

`distinct()` is too slow and I'm looking for a different solution to remove duplicates.

**P.S:**

I also tried to use this query instead of type_q, but it's slower than distinct! because type_ids is a very large list.

```
typ_ids = models.Catalogue.objects.only('type').filter(type__in=intersections).values_list('id', flat=True)
type_q = Q(id__in=typ_ids)
```

Comment: Have you tried using set...?

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha Where and how use that?!

Comment: `set(Catalogue.objects.only('type').filter(type__in=intersections).values_list('id', flat=True))` ... like this... you can use wherever required. Please note this will not give you queryset.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha If I use type_ids, it's not necessary to use set or distinct ... in fact, it first retrieve distinct ids based on type, and then filter Catalogue based on these ids ... The problem is that type_ids is a very large list and ```type_q = Q(id__in=typ_ids)``` takes a long time

Comment: In the question you have posted where exactly do you want to apply distinct... Its not clear nor have you mentioned in the question... Please update the question where you have  used distinct()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235266/discussion-between-shivendra-pratap-kushwaha-and-omid-jahadi).

Comment: Have you tried create a raw sql  since you are fetching only one value with `flat=True`, i think it will be quite easy to write it for example; `Catalogue.objects.raw(SELECT myapp_catalogue_id, FROM myapp_catalogue JOIN myapp_m2mtable ON myapp_m2mtable _id=myapp_m2mtable_id GROUP BY myapp_cataloge_id` group by is to return distinct without using distinct keyword. I am not totally sure that this works for couple reasons but you can create your own queries, u can find more detail in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: @berkeeb Thank you ... But raw SQL query is the last choice if there is no other answer with django orm